# What&#39;s the ratio of triangles made by diagonals of a trapezoid/trapezium?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Trapezoid]

In the above image, what will be the ratio of areas of triangle $A$ and $B$?

From Googling, I've found that:

$\operatorname{Ar}(A) = \dfrac{a^2h}{2(a+b)}$

and

$\operatorname{Ar}(B) = \dfrac{b^2h}{2(a+b)}$

but how do I get these formulas from the classic formula of $\dfrac{\rm base \times height}2$?!

Basically, how were the formulas in this image:

[this image http://www.geometryexpressions.com/explorations/04-Examples/02-Example_Book/02-Quadrilaterals/Example%20036-Areas_Of_Triangles_In_A_Trapezoid_files/image004.gif](http://www.geometryexpressions.com/explorations/04-Examples/02-Example_Book/02-Quadrilaterals/Example%20036-Areas_Of_Triangles_In_A_Trapezoid_files/image004.gif)

figured out?

Comment: Oh, and reference link: [Geometry Expressions](http://www.geometryexpressions.com/explore.php?p=04-Examples%2F02-Example_Book%2F02-Quadrilaterals&f=Example+036-Areas_Of_Triangles_In_A_Trapezoid.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, what is the height of the triangle $\Delta a$? It is similar to the triangle $\Delta b$ (why?), so and the heights $h_a$ of $\Delta a$ and $h_b$ of $\Delta b$ are related in the following way:

First, we have $h = h_a + h_b$. This is obvious if you draw them on your figure. Secondly, from similarity, we have that
$$
\frac{h_b}{h_a} = \frac{b}{a}.
$$
By manipulating the last equation, and with a little help from the first to rid ourselves of $h_b$, we get
$$
\frac{h-h_a}{h_a} = \frac{b}{a} \\\\
\frac{h}{h_a} - 1 = \frac{b}{a} \\\\
\frac{h}{h_a} = 1 + \frac{b}{a} \\\\
h_a = \frac{h}{1 + \frac{b}{a}} = \frac{ha}{a + b}
$$
This means that the area of $\Delta a$ is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot a \cdot h_a = \frac{1}{2}\cdot a \cdot \frac{ha}{a + b} = \frac{a^2h}{2(a+b)}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Great explanation! :)

Comment: One thing, though, how is $1 + b/a$ = $a + b$?

Comment: It isn't. The $a$ in the denominator was 'thrown' up.

Comment: @ohad Now I feel dumb... Thanks for explaining this!