# Triangles formed by diagonals of trapezoids

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image: Generic trapezoid image]

$\Delta$ AOB and $\Delta$ DOC should be equal in area. Correct me if I am wrong.

Given: Trapezoid ABCD with ratio $\frac{area \Delta AOB}{area\Delta ABD}$ = $\frac{3}{4}$.

I am trying to find (1) Ratio of Area $\Delta$AOD to $\Delta$BOC; (2) Ratio of Area $\Delta$COD to Trapezoid ABCD

I know that the final solution (1) is 1:9 and (2) is 3:16, but I do not understand how to get to these answers.

Please explain how to get to the answer, and if possible, how might I find different ratios like $\Delta$BDC to trapezoid ABCD, or $\Delta$BDC to $\Delta$ABD?

*Note: I have also seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430159/whats-the-ratio-of-triangles-made-by-diagonals-of-a-trapezoid-trapezium) but I'm not sure it's relevant to what I'm asking.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the result of that post to conclude that the ratio is

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$

The ratio is also

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2} a h_1}{\frac{1}{2} b h_2}$$

where $h_1,h_2$ are heights of $\Delta AOD$ and $\Delta BOC$, respectively. Now since

$$\frac{\text{area} \Delta AOB}{\text{area} \Delta ABD}=\frac{3}{4}$$

$$\frac{h_1}{h_2}=\frac{1}{3}$$

which gives you

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}=\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$$

So $\frac{a}{b}=1/3$, that means the ratio of area of $\Delta AOD$ and $\Delta BOC$ is $1:9$.

I think you can then find the other one using similar argument.

Comment: What is _a_ and _b_?

Comment: @Rex AD and BC, respectively, in the notation of the question you quoted.